# GameObject mesh.vertices array is empty

Tags: unity, c#, geometry, 3d-meshes, vertex

I've an Icosphere GameObject:

[image]

I want to iterate over each of the faces and change the material based on their distance from the center, however I don't seem to be able to retrieve the list of vertices for the object:

```
void Start()
{
    // Works
    _planetRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    _planetRenderer.sharedMaterial = Materials.First(m => m.name == "Sand");

    // Can't retrieve vertices
    MeshFilter gameObjMeshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();

    Debug.Log($"Center: {transform.position}");
    Debug.Log($"Mesh Count: {gameObjMeshFilter.mesh.vertices.Length}");
}
```

The vertexCount is returned as 43530, but vertices is an empty array:

[image]

Comment: Is the mesh marked as CPU readable in its import settings?

Comment: @DMGregory Think that was it, enabling Read/Write resolved the issue, please feel free to post as an answer, thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit tied up just now. Can you post your own answer? You've got screenshots of the relevant setting/results more handy than I do. 

Comment: No prob, appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Using OnBecameVisible seems to retrieve the values, I'm not sure if that's what I want in this case though?

```
void OnBecameVisible()
{
    MeshFilter gameObjMeshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();

    Debug.Log($"Center: {transform.position}");
    Debug.Log($"Mesh Count: {gameObjMeshFilter.mesh.vertices.Length}");
}
```

[image]